# Average time and CPU Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to get the cpu usage and the execution time of a program in python. I have to make an average of 30 executions and **must use the `time` command (Linux)**. I've never worked with Linux before so I'm struggling to make it work. I've tried a number of ways and that's what I did so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

size=400
n_cpu=4

/usr/bin/time -f "CPU:  %p    TIME:  %e"
for i in {1..30};
do
    python "script.py" $size $size $n_cpu
done
```

Could someone tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash -x

size=400
n_cpu=4
trials=($(seq 1 30))

for trial in "${trials[@]}"
do
    { time -p python "script.py" $size $size $n_cpu; } 2> $trial.time
done 

# optional aggregation and cleanup
cat *.time > trials.txt && rm -rf *.time
```

After that, you could pull `trials.txt` into an R or Python script to calculate runtime statistics (mean, std. deviation, etc.).